# Could not find a credentials file | Google Analytics

Tags: laravel

I implement google analytics in Laravel but it's showing me error

> Could not find a credentials file at `C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinefreetools\storage\google/g-ana.json`.

I guess it's on right place on root directory of Laravel I created a folder google and save file inside it and also its showing storage in error don't know why?

here is path

'service_account_credentials_json' => storage_path('google/g-ana.json'),

Answer (score 0):

guys sorry for posting but it saves others time I have solved just now so the answer is just put the file where packages want in my case package want file in storage folder, so I tried and its solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).